# Kops/Kubernetes instance group autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling, kubectl, kops

I have a Kubernetes cluster running in AWS. I used `kops` to setup and start the cluster.

I defined a minimum and maximum number of nodes in the nodes instance group:

```
apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-07-03T15:37:59Z
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: k8s.tst.test-cluster.com
  name: nodes
spec:
  image: kope.io/k8s-1.6-debian-jessie-amd64-hvm-ebs-2017-05-02
  machineType: t2.large
  maxSize: 7
  minSize: 5
  role: Node
  subnets:
  - eu-central-1b
```

Currently the cluster has 5 nodes running. After some deployments in the cluster, pods/containers cannot start because there are no nodes available with enough resources.

So I thought, when there is a resource problem, k8s scales automatically the cluster and start more nodes. Because the maximum number of nodes is 7.

Do I miss any configuration?

**UPDATE**

As @kichik mentioned, the autoscaler addon is already installed. Nevertheless, it doesn't work. Kube-dns is also often restarting because of resource problems.

Answer (score 1):

Someone opened a [ticket for this on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/341) and it suggests you have to install the [autoscaler addon](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/cluster-autoscaler). Check if it's already installed with:

```
kubectl get deployments --namespace kube-system | grep autoscaler
```

If it's not, you can install it with the following script. Make sure `AWS_REGION`, `GROUP_NAME`, `MIN_NODES` and `MAX_NODES` have the right values.

```
CLOUD_PROVIDER=aws
IMAGE=gcr.io/google_containers/cluster-autoscaler:v0.5.4
MIN_NODES=5
MAX_NODES=7
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
GROUP_NAME="nodes.k8s.example.com"
SSL_CERT_PATH="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" # (/etc/ssl/certs for gce)

addon=cluster-autoscaler.yml
wget -O ${addon} https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kops/master/addons/cluster-autoscaler/v1.6.0.yaml

sed -i -e "s@{{CLOUD_PROVIDER}}@${CLOUD_PROVIDER}@g" "${addon}"
sed -i -e "s@{{IMAGE}}@${IMAGE}@g" "${addon}"
sed -i -e "s@{{MIN_NODES}}@${MIN_NODES}@g" "${addon}"
sed -i -e "s@{{MAX_NODES}}@${MAX_NODES}@g" "${addon}"
sed -i -e "s@{{GROUP_NAME}}@${GROUP_NAME}@g" "${addon}"
sed -i -e "s@{{AWS_REGION}}@${AWS_REGION}@g" "${addon}"
sed -i -e "s@{{SSL_CERT_PATH}}@${SSL_CERT_PATH}@g" "${addon}"

kubectl apply -f ${addon}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not properly configured? Did you try dumping the deployment and verifying?